# Intellisense for protractor?

Tags: javascript, protractor, intellisense, pageobjects

I'm looking for any intellisense for protractor that will load required files.
For example I have this Page Object.

```
var example_page = function()
{
    this.abcde = element(by.model('abc'));
};
module.exports = new example_page();
```

And this spec file

```
describe('angularjs homepage', function() {
    var example_page = require('./example_po.js');
    example_page.abcde // I want intellisense that finds this property.
});
```

So basically I want intellisense that finds page objects and finds every property and function in them to display for me, because I'm tired of going from file to file looking for properties...

Comment: You can use `TypeScript`.

Comment: Do you have more information on that? Does it work with Page Objects?

Comment: `TypeScript` is a super-set of `JavaScript`. one of it's advantages is it's intel. you can add reference for any library definition then get the lib intel as well.

Comment: @FCin are you using any ide? bcoz I use VSCode and it displays the page objects functions, one more alternative is typescript as mentioned above

Comment: @RamPasala I used VSCode for a while, but it didn't show Page Objects for me, so that's why I asked the question :) How did you attach page objects in VSCode?

Comment: Hmm... you are exporting a reference of your function `module.exports = new example_page();`, I usually  export the function `module.exports = example_page;`and use the constructor inside my specs to create new reference of that function but still this should not affect it. I checked it works I am seeing the methods in both the ways.

Comment: Did you add any reference to page object except require('......')? What exactly is required for it to work?

Comment: I use webstorm and it works for me

Comment: I installed webstorm with angular-protractor yesterday and it doesn't work with page objects.